# C#: Put an exe file on the foreground of the form

Tags: c#, .net

I need to keep the exe's window (for example Notepad) always on the foreground of the form,
 it means that even if we click on the form , the exe's window will always be ahead of the form.
In other words,I have a button which when we click on it,it launches the exe and the exe's window
 will appear.If we click on the form the exe's window must remain at it's place.
This is what I did:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
       try
       {
           this.TopMost = false;
           string winpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
           myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
           myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = winpath+@"\system32\notepad.exe";
           myProcess.Start();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
```

Thank you.

Comment: TopMost is only for windows in a process, but not other process. If you click on that button, notepad will show. After that if you click on your windows again, notepad is going to background.

Comment: Normally Jeroen you are right but it is not working in my app...

Comment: The Windows API doesn't provide a way for your process to force another process's window to be top-most. The user can always cause some third process's window on top of both your process and Notepad. And you can't really link your window to Notepad's window. But you can add code to your program to force Notepad to be activated, by calling `SetActiveWindow()` or `SetForegroundWindow()`, any time your own program becomes the active window. Note however that this may cause some window flickering as your window momentarily is the foreground window and then is not again.